# Why won't my code read all the character strings in a 'for'?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char, scanf

If i run this code and choose 3 for *n* (the number of sentences read from the keyboard), it will allow me to only read two of them. What am i doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 20

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of sentences: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char** x = (char**)malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        *(x + i) = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    printf("Enter %d sentences of a maximum of %d characters:\n",n,MAX);
    char msj[MAX]="";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin.getline(msj, MAX);
        strcpy(*(x + i), msj);
    }
    printf("The sentences are:");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", *(x + i));
    }
    free(x);
}
```

Comment: You allocate n pointers correctly, but only allocate  memory for 1 char for each sentence.

Comment: Why are you using `malloc`, `scanf`, or `free`? If you want to use those functions, write C.  If you want to write in C++, do not use any of those.

Comment: This code is C. While simply adding `<iostream>` and `using namespace std`, requires the code to be compiled as C++, this is not remotely close to how C++ is actually written, or at least should be written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting to take the `'\n'` that was left in the input after you read n.

You can either change your scanf to: `scanf("%d\n", &n);` or add a `getchar();` right after it.

Also, as mentioned in comments, you are allocating a single char in each array. You should multiply the result `sizeof` by the number of letters you want + 1 (remember the `\0`.)

`*(x + i) = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * DESIRED_LENGTH);`

And at the end... you should also free all the pointers (before freeing x), other wise you would have a memory leak:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   free(*(x + i));
```